# Does Microsoft have any email markup that allow users to execute actions?

Tags: outlook

Does Microsoft have any kind of Email Markup like [Google Email Markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action) that allow users to execute actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing like that. The best you can do is have voting buttons.

Comment: @Dmitry_Streblechenko thank for the answer. I hope they implement something like that in the future.

Comment: Still relevant as of today, they didn't implemented something like that. I just had a contact with someone at Microsoft Outlook, we contacted them for that specific mater.

Answer (score 0):

This may be quite obsolete, but they have something called [Actionable Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages)